# tar czf with --remove-files and -c

Tags: linux, tar

When I want to tar from a dir and remove all the original files I used the below command:

```
tar -cvzf /xx/yy/data-backup.tar.gz  --remove-files -C /aa/daily-backup/ .
```

All the files under /aa/daily-backup/ is tarred and removed successfully.
But on the end of the output of the terminal, it shows:

```
tar:  /aa/daily-backup/ .: Cannot rmdir:Invalid argument
```

If I remove the `--remove-files`, this command will run successfully.
Obviously, I don't want to remove the `/aa/daily-backup/`, how should I revise my command?

Comment: *zipped*?  .....

Comment: sorry for the confusion, tar

Comment: I don't get `Cannot rmdir:Invalid argument` error with `tar 1.30` after running this command: `tar -cvzf data-backup.tar.gz  --remove-files -C /aa/daily-backup/ .`

Comment: Thanks for the verification.It works fine on my ubuntu...but seems which also remove the daily-backup directory...but I only want to tar the files under the dir and remove them...